# Как поменять title главной страницы в Joomla

Tags: joomla

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]В панели администратора не могу найти. Прошу помочь.

Менял - не меняется title. Не могу понять, в title на главной есть текст, а где он прописан - полдня убил - никак не найду. А там где указано стрелкой - прописывал - ничего в title не меняется

Comment: а зачем мне на странице заголовок? Эта галочка дает возможность публикации на самой странице текста, который указан выше, но не в title. Не надо умничать, если не знаешь

Comment: ах да сори, не туда смотрел ) никто не умничает... к вашему сведению, я часто переписываю админку для Joomla и всегда туда вставляю дополнительную галочку для браузера, вот и забыл что это в стандарте нет, вот поэтому не надо умничать, если не знаете ))

Comment: Если по стандарту не показывает, возможно компонент магазина, переписывает стандартную возможность, посмотрите в компоненте возможно есть пункт для заполнения title для браузера

Comment: Я в структуре Joomla не силен - второй день, как открыл. Компонент - это в структуре папок components? Или где-то в админке? А злой я потому, что убил почти день на поиск.

Comment: Большое спасибо за намек! Это действительно было в компонентах для магазина.

Comment: вот и хорошо ) )

Answer (score 1):

Там где у вас в пункте меню главная страница стоит. Редактируете этот пункт меню. Во вкладке "Параметры страницы", поле "Заголовок страницы в браузере".

Comment: ничего не выходит - менял. Сейчас скриншот выложу.